# How to create a pdf file on the fly and make it an email attachment?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

The tutorials I found for sending an `email` with attachment are based on an already created file. But my need is to create a `pdf` file on the fly and attach it to an email. How to do that ?

Comment: What did you try so far?

Answer (score 1):

Most PDF generators support writing to an `OutputStream`. One solution is to use a `FileOutputStream`, save the PDF to disk, create the mail (using the tutorials you have), send the mail, delete the file.

The other option is to use `ByteArrayOutputStream` (use the one from [commons-lang3](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-lang/), since the one in the Java runtime is very slow for large files). Use that to generate the "file". When the PDF is created, use `getByteArray()` and put that into a `ByteArrayInputStream` which you should be able to use as a mail attachment.

Comment: I will go for your second suggestion then :) thnx

Comment: Keep an eye on how big those files can be. Many mail servers delete attachments that are too big plus it can make your JVM crash with OutOfMemory error. You need about 5 times the memory of each PDF per mail to handle them.